# Other ways to check function's output?

Tags: php, function, class

A question from an obvious PHP newbie here.

I have a class that has two functions inside. I am trying to check the output of the first function using the second function (like in the code below). The problem with this is the output (1) is already being displayed in the if-statement line. Here's the result:

1Flag is: 1

So the question is, how can I do this without the output being displayed inside the if statement?

```
class Test{

    public $flag;

    private function func_one(){
        $this->flag = 1;
        echo $this->flag;
        return $this->flag;
    }

    public function display_func(){
        if ( !empty( $this->func_one() ) ){
            echo 'Flag is: ';
            $this->func_one();
        }

        // if ( $this->func_one() === 1 ){
        //  echo 'Flag is: ';
        //  $this->func_one();  
        // }

        //var_dump( $this->func_one() );
    }
}

$classTest = new Test();
$classTest->display_func();
```

Comment: remove `echo $this->flag;` ?

Comment: ... and use string concatenation to display the value: `echo 'Flag is: ' . $this->func_one();`

Comment: There is a lot wrong in this code... your function at once ASSIGN, ECHO and RETURN ...

Comment: Just removing the echo resulted to "Flag: ". Adding @ThomasDavidPlat suggestion did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the return val in a variable and run comparisons on that

```
if ( !empty( $this->func_one() ) ){
    echo 'Flag is: ';
    $this->func_one();
}
```

Should be

```
$val=$this->func_one();
if (!empty($val)){
      echo "Flag is: $val";
}
```

Also remove the echo from `func_one()`, just return the value. This allows you to call the method only once and make your decisions based on the value that was returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test{
public $flag;
private function func_one(){
    $this->flag = 1;
    return $this->flag;
}
public function display_func(){
    if ( !empty( $this->func_one() ) ){
        $result=$this->func_one();
        echo 'Flag is: '.$result;
    }
    }
}
$classTest = new Test();
$classTest->display_func();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `echo` from `func_one()`

Comment: Just doing this resulted to "Flag: ".

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement: `if ( !empty( $this->func_one() ) )` calls `func_one()` and `func_one()`'s second line is `echo $this->flag;`. That is why the output is being displayed in the if statment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `echo` from first function.

Also, in the second function, concatenate the output returned from first function.

So, following are the changes:

```
private function func_one(){
    $this->flag = 1;
    //echo $this->flag; -> remove this
    return $this->flag;
}

public function display_func(){

    if ( !empty( $this->func_one() ) ){
        echo 'Flag is: ' .$this->func_one(); // Also, observe the changes on this line.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the if condition form the second function. see below code.

class Test {

```
public $flag;

private function func_one() {
    $this->flag = 1;
    echo $this->flag;
    return $this->flag;
}

public function display_func() {

    //if ( !empty( $this->func_one() ) ){
    echo 'Flag is: ';
    $this->func_one();
    //}
    // if ( $this->func_one() === 1 ){
    //  echo 'Flag is: ';
    //  $this->func_one();  
    // }
    //var_dump( $this->func_one() );
}
```

}

$classTest = new Test();
$classTest->display_func();

Your result = Flag is: 1

========================================

You can also write you code like this way

class Test {

```
public $flag;

private function func_one() {
    $this->flag = 1;
    return $this->flag;
}

public function display_func() {
    echo 'Flag is: '.$this->func_one();
}
```

}

$classTest = new Test();
$classTest->display_func();